# CSS property, cursor:pointer, works at a certain window width, meanwhile on other it disappears

Tags: css, cursor, media-queries, width, toggle

The proprety of the `#toggle` (div) should be `cursor:pointer` and the toggle should appear from 0 to - 877px (screen - width).

Toggle works, it appears from 0 to 877px , also the `cursor:pointer` property does work ranging from 427px width to 877px width. But from min - 426px, the `cursor:pointer doesn't work.

What is the issue?`

My code:

```css
#toggle {
  float: right;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 10%;
  visibility: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#toggle .line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 3px auto;
}

#toggle.on #one {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(1px) translateY(5px);
}

#toggle.on #two {
  opacity: 0;
}

#toggle.on #three {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(5px) translateY(-9px);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 877px) {
  ul {
    display: none;
  }
  #toggle {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>

  <div id="wrapper">

    <div id="toggle">
      <div id="one" class="line"> </div>
      <div id="two" class="line"> </div>
      <div id="third" class="line"> </div>

    </div>

    <div class="logo">
      <h2> Navbar </h2>
    </div>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"> Home </a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> About </a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Pricings </a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Blog </a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="exclusive"> Contact </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div id="#content">

</div>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine for me.  What browser are you using?

Comment: Mozila, Chrome. It does work as i mentioned from 427 px to 877px. But a mininmal browser screen width  - 426 px, doesn't.

Comment: It worked on both firefox  62 and chrome 49 at 350px for me

Comment: For me it doesn't work. Even when inspecting elements with browser developer tools, at 427-877px it's completly possible to inspect this specific element (when also the pointer - property works), but as it gets smaller its just simply dissapears, so i can only inspect, navbar, which does have 2 Elements, menu, logo, meanwhile toggle is entirly forgoten about. Still Thanks four your help tho!

Comment: Fixed, its started working. Thanks for help.